# Google Fonts much quicker than Typekit

Tags: fonts

I am using a web font. Both Google Fonts and Typekit provide the same font (Merriweather). I have tried both services. Much to my surprise Typekit was visually noticably slower at delivering the font; there was the flash of unstyled text. Whereas with Google there was no flash of unstyled font. I've search but no one else seems to be commenting on the speed difference between the two services. Is this a known difference?

The other thing that was noticable was that the Typekit version of the font looked very different; bolder/fatter/blacker and not so weedy thin looking. I presume this is because they are using the latest version of the font. Presumably the same font wouldn't look different (the aliasing) depending on who serves up the font?

Comment: Don't presume. Look it up. What does the CSS that you got from both tell you? And are the files they reference the same, or are they different versions? (these things can be fairly easily checked with dev tools). As for the slowness, that'll probably entirely depend on how close you are to CDN nodes for both their networks. Google is everywhere on the planet, Typekit is mostly North America, so outside of that region google is probably faster, but: ask them. Even tweeting at Typekit typically gets you a response fairly fast.

Comment: From the typographers blog I am aware that there is an updated version of the font (version 1.2 for example). However Dev Tools doesn't provide information on the version of the font that is being served up. I have asked the typographer what version Typekit and Google are providing, but I have not heard from him. I'm not on Twitter, but will attempt to contact Typekit and ask them what version they are using and if they have servers in the UK / Europe. I guess not because it is painfully slow compared to the same font from Google.

Comment: dev tools does show you the actual font URL that is used to download the font, so you can just run that in isolation, download the file to your download folder, and then check the font properties to see where they differ.

Comment: I've checked the fonts in Google Dev Tools. It doesn't say what version of the font is being provided (1.1 or 1.2), nor is it possible to download the font to a computer to check (if this were possible it would be possible to copy/steal paid for fonts). I'm awaiting a response from Typekit.

Comment: Note that it is in fact entirely possible to download the font, because otherwise the browser wouldn't be able to use it for styling. The delivery might be as a datauri, but dropping that in you url bar will decode it as file: anything that your browser can show you, it has to download first, and anything your browser can download, you can inspect and work with too. It's only really "secure" by making it more work than just clicking on a link, and doing intelligent subsetting, but that last bit might be the cause: analyising the page for subsetting is slower than blindly getting a font-face.